# Overwriting linux (read-only) root from running system

Tags: linux, partitioning, read-only

This seems to be a very generic problem to me. I have an embedded system running Linux from a read-only root. There is an updater daemon that installs new software images when available by overwriting whole partitions. My question is: What is the best approach to do this from a running system?

1. dd the updated partition to `/dev/sdX`, which is the currently
   (read-only) mounted root?
2. move the current root using `pivot_root` to a tmpfs as discussed [here](/q/918134/)?
3. use 2 root partitions and toggle the "active" one after every update?

The downsides of 2 and 3 are, that I need lots of RAM (for 2) or disk space (for 3). Is there a safe way to overwrite the read-only root partition from a running system and rebooting into the updated system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did is, I went with the 1. approach and ran into much trouble where the system wasn't stable anymore due to filesystem problem. I guess overwriting a mounted partition is no a good idea (no big surprise though).
To fix this, I tried the 2. idea (pivot_root) which works but has some downsides. One is: You have to stop most of the running processes and/or reboot as soon as possible after the update is complete.
Finnaly, I tried the 3. idea and the only downside is the "waste" of disk space. Everything else works pretty well.